# Beginning Hour: What are the minimum requirements to get the true ending?

Tags: resident-evil-7

This question relates to the Resident Evil 7 demo, which is subtitled "Beginning Hour".

There are a number of different endings to this demo, and I don't know how many different ones there are, but my question is: What are the minimum requirements for achieving the true/best ending?

I guess I am looking for the shortest list of steps that will result in the true ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a fair bit of searching I have found [this guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=821597177). The guide is actually for obtaining the 'dirty coin' but it also happens to result in the 'true ending'. Using this guide I have managed to work out the minimum steps in takes to get the true ending:

1. Pull the hidden level in the fireplace to open the secret door
2. Enter the secret door and grab the fuse on the stool
3. Put the fuse in the fusebox (in the room where you start)
4. Go upstairs, activate the attic stairs, go up to the main room in he attic and grab the basement key next to the bed
5. Go to the basement to get the attic window key, at this point a Molded will spawn and you MUST get out of the basement without taking any damage
6. Return to the attic and escape out of the window (up the ladders) using the key

Essentially, you just need to escape without taking any damage and you will get the true ending.

---

TIP for step 5:

1. Grab the key then immediately run past the Molded (sometimes it will hit you, sometimes it will miss)
2. Immediately try to open the door to get the animation started
3. Turn around and get into a position where the hanging body bag is between you and the Molded. Kick it into the Molded so it gets knocked to the floor
4. Run to the door and keep trying it until you get through - you should get enough time before the Molded gets back up and attacks you.

It may take a few attempts to pull this off, but it is very doable once you get the hang of it.

Comment: On a side note: Where the molded spawns depends on what you do in the basement.  If you try to go for the key first, it will break the shelves and come through.  If you try to open the door first, it will fall onto the floor of the first room instead.

Comment: A second strategy (and iirc the way the game expects you to play) is to grab the valve, leave the room, get the gun from the bathroom, and when you return, shoot the Molded to stun it before grabbing the key.  Any time you return to the basement, the Molded does the "drop into the first room" bit like he does if you'd tried to open the basement door the first time.